# Database error when starting docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

When I create the container and run it, the database throws error 1. If I run it again, everything works. This container is for fastapi tests; again, when first launched, the tests do not work because they cannot connect to the database. If I launch a container on gunicorn or uvicorn, the database will also not start up the first time
My docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASS}"
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
    container_name: db_container_tests
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "%{POSTGRES_USER}", "-d", "ylab_db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 80s

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-tests
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASS}"
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DB_NAME}"
    container_name: api_container_tests
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: sh -c "alembic upgrade head && pytest -v -s test/"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: I don’t know how to share the log, but after the error [30] locale, the container with the API starts, then the container with the database starts again